# How do I stop Symfony 2 checkbox from returning null

Tags: symfony, checkbox, symfony-forms

On my Symfony 2 form I have 2 checkboxes. The documentation states

> "if the box is checked, the field will be set to true, if the box is
>   unchecked, the value will be set to false"

which is what I'd like to happen but when the checkbox is unchecked I'm actually getting nothing back. I realise a checkbox on a HTML form will normally return nothing if unchecked and I'd usually add some logic to the back end to handle it but it sounds like Symfony should be doing that for me and isn't.

What am I doing wrong or have I missed?

My formtype looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('fullname', 'text')
            ->add('screened', 'checkbox', array(
                'label'     => 'Enable screening emails?' ))
            ->add('dedupe', 'checkbox', array(
                'label'     => 'Enable live dedupeing?'))
 );)
```

and  the relevant bits of the twig template look like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox col-sm-6">
            {{ form_widget(form.screened) }}
            {{ form_label(form.screened) }}
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox col-sm-6">
            {{ form_widget(form.dedupe, {'attr': {'required': 'false'}}) }}
            {{ form_label(form.dedupe) }}
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The form is created in the controler here:

```
/**
     * Creates a new User entity.
     *
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new User();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $this->get('project_login.user_manager')->setUserPassword($entity, $form->get('password')->getData());

            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return $this->render('ProjectLoginBundle:User:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to create a User entity.
     *
     * @param User $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createCreateForm(User $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_create'),
            'method' => 'POST', 'validation_groups' => array('create')
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

        return $form;
    }
```

Comment: It is not really clear to me what is the problem... Can you please clarify?

Comment: When the form is submitted and the check box is unchecked the value of the checkbox is not returned. Thios is what I would expect from a HTML form but the Symfony documentation days that when unchecked it should be returning False. Why am I getting nothing rather than false?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well you need to handle when the field is not checked, because you're not getting a response when you're handling the form request

You can solve it in this way:

```
 if ($form->isValid()) {
     $form->handleRequest($request);

     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

     $entity = $form->getData();

     var_dump($entity->getScreened());
     var_dump($entity->getFullname());
     var_dump($entity->getDedupe());

     // They should return you the values set on the create form
     $em->persist($entity);
     $em->flush();
 }
```

In case that it is not getting the values try in this way, but is not the proper one...

```
if (!isset($form->get('screened')) {
    $entity->setScreened(false);
}

if (!isset($form->get('dedupe')) {
    $entity->setDedupe(false);
}
```

It will check if you're not receiving any data for dedupe and screened from the form, if it's this case you'll know that the value has not been checked

Comment: Yes as I said I would normally (in standard PHP) handle the the absence of a value in the back end but the Symfony documentation says that I don't need to, it should be handling it for me.

Comment: Are you mapping the field with an entity attribute? The data_class is related with some entity?

Comment: Not sure what you mean my that. The form is mapped to a user entity on creation and screened and dedupe are fields in the user entitiy. I'll edit my question add that code.\

Comment: If I was going to add the code you suggest to set the absent values, where would I need to put it?

Comment: Try to dump $form->getData(), if the form is associated to the entity you shouldn't need to set the values later, $form->getData() should return you the entity $user because is already mapped, I'll update my answer

Comment: That returns bool(false) but that is because the getScreened() fuction is "return ($this->screened > 0);" and the value of $screened is NULL so the function returns FALSE. The setScreened() function never gets called when the check box is unchecked because the screened property is missing from the $request

Comment: Ok if screened just has value when is checked, try this hack that I wrote you below, ask if the $request has the value screened, if it doesn't mean that it's unchecked